# After which methods call java send real request to server?

Tags: java, http, connection, request, inputstream

For example, I have the java code below:

```
URL u = new URL("http://google.com");  
URLConnection c = u.openConnection();  
InputStream s = c.getInputStream();  
int i;  
while ((i = s.read()) != -1) {  
     //do something here  
}
```

And I cant understand, in which moment (after which method call) java sends the actual request to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THe openConnection() method of the URL class, just returns you a new instance of [HttpUrlConnection](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java.html)(because your protocol is http).
The actual connection doesent happen until you call the getInputStream() or getOutputStream() methods. It's on the call of these methods that connect() is called and the google server receives the connection. And because the protocol is http, the server would return you the google home page, which you are reading using s.read(). (it should give you the html page of google home page)

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Correct answer below: For more sophisticated requests, you can call the URL object's openConnection() method to obtain a HttpURLConnection object. You can prepare this object with additional information before issuing the request. To make the request, you call a method on the URLConnection such as getInputStream() or getOutputStream().

Answer (score 2):

It happens during the `openConnection()` method.  You can tell this by reading its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29)

> A new connection is opened every time by calling the openConnection method of the protocol handler for this URL.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `openConnection` it is actually trying to create connection with specified url and in case it fails then throws `IOException`.

*openConnection* - new connection is opened every time by calling the openConnection method of the protocol handler for this URL.